# How to pass data from action to loader in React Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using React-Router-Dom to process a delete action.

```
<Form method="delete" action="destroy">
    <input type="hidden" name="toyName" id="toyName" value={toy.name} />
    <input type="hidden" name="toyDescription" id="toyDescription" value={toy.description} />
    <Button type="submit" variant="danger" className="float-end">Delete</Button>
</Form>
```

Inside `index.js` I use action to process the deletion send the user to a `DeletedView` to confirm to the user that the item has been deleted. The `loader` function is meant to pass the form data to the view. However, I am unable to pass the data from `action` to `loader`. The `params` and `request` variables in the `loader` do not contain any output from the `action` return function. How do I do so?

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
    /*** some other code ***/
    {
        path: "/toys/:toyId/destroy",
        element: <DeletedView />,
        loader: async({request, params}) => {
            console.log(request); // does not contain form data
            console.log(params); // does not contain form data
            return [request, params]; // data sent to the DOM for display...
        },
        action: async ({request, params}) => {

            //data contains the toyName and toyDescription values
            const data = Object.fromEntries(await request.formData());

            if (request.credentials === "same-origin") {
                axios.delete(`${url}/toys/${params.toyId}`)
                    .then(response => {
                        return [response, data];
                    }, error => {
                        return error;
                    });
            }
            return;
        }
    },
    /*** some other code ***/
])
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `DeletedView`, I initially used `useLoaderData()`. However, changing this to `useActionData()` solved my problem.